# In what point embedded video will started download the stream data? Is it when directly render it or when we try to play it?

Tags: html, performance, iframe, youtube

I know this is a strange question, but When my friend ask me regarding this, I become quite confused since this is matter for our **landing page performance** and I'm not quite sure regarding this. So this is my question:

**Let say, in my landing page, we usually have a total size around 300Kb after build (this is already include all of the asset, without any embedded video). But recently we want to revamp it and our opinion split into two:**

1. **Where in My opinion when we embedded the video (from youtube or local) it will directly download when we open the page, so it means our user will need to await around (n * 1Mb) size until it open and it will take a lot of time (let us exclude lazy load for now since our main concern is how much data that user will need to open our landing page)**
2. **While My friend told me that it will only stream the data (download the data from server) when we play it. Unless we make it auto play**

So our concern regarding this problem is that:

**What if 1 embedded video have a size of 1-5 Mb (minimum) and we want to embed around 5 - 10 (minimum 5 video) video for our every feature we have in our landing page (we can input it in local files or Youtube, so bear in mind that the major case is around this two embedded method). So, isn't it will make Our page really slow since it need around `300 + (n*1000*5) Kb` for open it in minimum video condition if it directly download the data when we only render it, or it will only download it after we `click the play button`**

for example this is our simple embedded method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Embedded Video</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>List of Features:</h1>

<div>
  <h2>Feature 1</h2>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/p_7dKsgXgV8" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Feature 2</h2>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/p_7dKsgXgV8" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Feature 3</h2>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/p_7dKsgXgV8" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Feature 4</h2>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/p_7dKsgXgV8" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

... 

<div>
  <h2>Feature N</h2>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/p_7dKsgXgV8" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

can someone explain it to me regarding this video embedded can affect our landing page performance? it make me quite confused regarding this.

P.S:
Oh if you can, can explain what if we using `<video>` or `<audio>` tag too, is it have the same case as above too?